# add external jar to an android project *manually* (without eclipse etc)

Tags: android, jar, adb

my problem is simple:
in the web there are numerous ways and tutorials on how to include jars in an android application through eclipse, android studio etc.
I want to do it manually; so, I want to know which files do I have to edit to bind my app
with the specific jars.

Comment: can i ask why you don't want to use eclipse or other program?

Comment: because I am sick and tired with the lagging Eclipse and the still bug-laden Android Studio. Also, I want to get to know Android's innards better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the web there are numerous ways and tutorials on how to include jars in an android application through eclipse, android studio

That is because the use of third-party libraries is tied to the build system being used to build the app.

> I want to do it manually

It is unclear what "manually" means in this context.

If you mean that you are using Ant, just put the JAR(s) in your project's `libs/` directory, and you are done. Note that this will work with Eclipse as well.

If you mean that you are using Gradle, you will need something like this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Or, if the JARs can be found in a Maven or Ivy repository, you can reference those as well, by defining the repository in the `repositories` block and then simply specifying the artifact in the `compile` directive:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. Your answer led me to suspect that the reason for my project failing to compile was not the dependencies, but the the dreaded R error itself.